# This window keeps popping up and wont go away.. help?

Tags: finder, catalina

This window keeps popping up on my Mac ever since I updated the OS to Catalina.

I tried searching for the file and selecting "show in finder" but nothing is there? Can anyone help me fix this problem? Very irritating to have this little box on my screen all the time.

[image]

Comment: Is it always exactly the same name, or are they random?

Comment: From a terminal screen try to and find the file and what is trying to open it

To see what has it open, use
    sudo lsof | grep <filename>

To find the file itself, use find
    sudo find / -name filename

Comment: I’m happy to help with terminal, but you should consider this malware and check you have decent backups or get a new drive and make one backup just in case you need to erase things or it’s not harmless adware.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely malware. Update your Apple software every week (or even every day) for a while in case Apple detects and blocks this specific app. It’s not behaving like a proper app should.

Any chance you can locate the file in finder and upload it to virus total?

- [“qnmqkmkrqwfq” is damaged and can’t be opened , even though i set Allow applications downloaded from: Anywhere](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378071/qnmqkmkrqwfq-is-damaged-and-can-t-be-opened-even-though-i-set-allow-applicat)

If you can get the finder window open, control click and show package contents and consider uploading the file to https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload if you’re not comfortable using terminal to type the command file and drag the bookmark “file” into the terminal window to check if the file is deceiving you - named like a text file but actually a program.