# How to resolve a '"file" is damaged and can't be opened' problem on Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina, error, file

This error message continually pops up, "geohxjhmvzab" is damaged and can't be opened.  I have searched, via FINDER, for the file, but to no avail.  I have also attempted to delete the file via TERMINAL, using an xattr command, to no avail.

Comment: Where do you get this message?  Can you post a screen shot?  Can you tell us what you’re doing in terminal when trying to search/delete the file?

Comment: Probably related: [“qnmqkmkrqwfq” is damaged and can’t be opened , even though i set Allow applications downloaded from: Anywhere](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378071/qnmqkmkrqwfq-is-damaged-and-can-t-be-opened-even-though-i-set-allow-applicat)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  If you can upload the file to virus total, please make an edit and a flag. This is likely malware so it’s not going to be a quick trash to clean up.